# Extract nodes based on attribute and node values

Tags: xml, xpath

For the below XML, I'm trying to extract the nodes based on attribute and node values.

Based on attribute class=pass and h1 contains ('objectives'), I'm trying to extract the below output.

"objectives" is a part of the node value string "1 task objectives"

1 task objectives
object1
object2

```
<body>
  <article>
    <body>
      <section>
        <h1>intro1</h1>
        <region>introd1</region>
        <region>introd2</region>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h1 class="pass">1 task objectives</h1>
        <region>object1</region>
        <region>object2</region>
      </section>
    </body>
  </article>
</body>
```

Below is the XPath expression I am trying. However, this is not giving any output. Can you please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
//body//section//h1[contains(.,'objectives') and @class="pass"]/*/text()
```

Thanks & Regards,
Simak

Comment: Sure Don. The output I am expecting for h1 class=pass and element value like '%objectives%' is:  1 task objectves    object1     object2

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the `h1` element but only operating within its children nodes.  The xpath expression that you need is:

```
//body//section//h1[contains(.,'objectives') and @class='pass']/../*/text()
```

Note the `..` which scopes back out to the parent of the `h1` element and then operates on the parents' children instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//body/section/h1[contains(.,'objectives') and @class='pass']/..//text()
```