# xpath search based on attribute and node value

Tags: xml, xpath

'I tried looking at  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108124/extract-nodes-based-on-attribute-and-node-values) but it wasn't much help but it's close to what I'm struggling with/need.

I have Solr formatted xml like this:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">1212</field>
<field name="web.header">Enrollment List</field>
<field name="web.title">Enrollment List</field>
<field name="web.body">.....<field>
<field name="web.collection">edu</field>
..
</doc>
<doc>
...
</doc>
</add>
```

and I am trying to pull the records with an attribute node of `<field name="web.collection">` and that has the node value of 
edu, org, com (that is I need each `<doc>`..`</doc>` record with the attribute web.collection that has a value of edu, org or com).

What would be the expression used? I've tried to use /add/doc/field[@name='web.collection'] with an assortment of contains/ AND operators but I get syntax error. Can someone help?

Comment: You're close. Try [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/f20818225a102da35c3cc291f988fd01): `/add/doc[field[@name='web.collection']='edu']`

Comment: is there a way to use an OR operand?

Comment: Yes, here's an [example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b1af50564bcfdcd8d5025e5fda6f2a98): `/add/doc[field[@name='web.collection']='edu' or field[@name='web.collection']='org']`

Comment: Right on, this works. Thanks sbat!